# Regexpression for getting a file

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi

I have to get a file through PDI based on the filename and i want to select file with name matching pattern **eligible_for_push** which has to be at the end.The file can be .txt or .csv
Please Help
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two part to your query:

**1. Finding all files ending with "eligible_for_push":**

You cannot use regex to find this sort of pattern *(at least i am not aware of)*. So as an alternate do the following:

Search all the files in the path using "Get Filename" steps. Use modified Javascript to find out the file ending with the above pattern. Check the JS file below.

[image]

**2. Files can be ".txt" or ".csv":**

You can use the below regex/wildcard to find choose between either .txt or .csv

```
.*\.txt|.*\.csv
```

Note : Use this code once you have filtered out the files ending with "eligible_for_push". The above JS ignore all the file patterns. After that use the second step to sort out all the .txt or .csv files.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: hi, could you please let me know the reg ex that I am supposed to used for *sampleFile.csv....I am getting issue if I use .*sampleFile.csv or .\*sampleFile.csv

Comment: @Ghost Rider you can use filter steps in your case.

Comment: some how it was working if I use ".*sampleFile.*.csv"...sorry for the trouble